# Find the limit of the sequence with sqrt

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate
$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac {\sqrt[n]{n^{2}}-3\sqrt[n]{n}+2} {\sqrt[n]{n^{4}}+2\sqrt[n]{n^{2}}-3}}$?
I am not allowed to use anything other than the following facts:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac {1}{n}}=0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{n}} =1$

If $y_n \le x_n \le z_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} {y_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} {z_n}=a$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {x_n}=a$

I find $y_n = \frac {-\sqrt[n]{n}}{8\sqrt[n]{n^4}}$.
But I don't know what is $z_n$ with $\lim z_n = -\frac {1}{8}$?

Help me find the limit of the sequence $x_n$, please

Comment: Hint : $\sqrt[n]{n^k}=(\sqrt[n]{n})^k$ for every positive integer $k$

Comment: Take $\sqrt[n]{n}$ as $x$, then the limit turns into $\lim_{x\to1} (x^2-3x+2) / (x^4+2x^2-3)$. Now we can factorize it and cancel out $x-1$… Would you accept this kind of answer?

Comment: Y.D.X, Thanks! I think I got it. Thank you again :)

Comment: Besides, my numerical calculation shows that your $y_n \geq x_n$…